# How to test if an SQL connection is open in AS3?

Tags: sql, actionscript-3

I'm currently setting a boolen after I open an SQL connection, and using this to test the connection status in other parts of my code.

I'd like to get rid of the boolean and test the connection directly.

Is this the only way to do it...

```
if(conn.hasEventListener(SQLEvent.OPEN))...
```

...or is there an AS3 equivalent of conn.State?

Thank you.

Comment: it doesn't look like the code you provided will tell you if the connection is open. it just checks if there's an event listener added to the conn that waits for the OPEN event.

Answer (score 0):

The `SQLConnection` class already declares an instance property called `connected` which is true if the connection is open, and false otherwise.

```
if (connection.connected)
{
    // Do something here
}
```